# zebra datepicker position is not calculating while loading first time

Tags: php, jquery

zebra datepicker calender position is not calculating while loading first time.
The calender positions correctly, when i open the firebug and minimize it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
  $('input.datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker();
   }, 100);
});

 $('#datepicker-start_date1')
  .Zebra_DatePicker({direction: true,pair: $('#datepicker-ret_date1')});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manually change the zebra_datepicker.js file. In this file the position of the calendar is calculated based on the window position. I remove that calculation and give required values to the top and left
I change following code

```
h=c(window).width(),l=c(window).height(),f=c(window).scrollTop(),n=c(window).scrollLeft();
```

the new code is

```
h=c(window).width(),l=c(window).height(),f=300,n=463.5;
```